# Is Content-Transfer-Encoding an HTTP header?

Tags: http, base64, mime

I'm writing a web service that returns a base64-encoded PDF file, so my plan is to add two headers to the response:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

My question is: Is `Content-Transfer-Encoding` a valid HTTP header?  I think it might only be for MIME.  If not, how should I craft my HTTP response to represent the fact that I'm returning a base64-encoded PDF?  Thanks.

**EDIT:**

It looks like HTTP does not support this header.  From [RFC2616 Section 14](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> Note: while the definition of Content-MD5 is exactly the same for HTTP
>   as in RFC 1864 for MIME entity-bodies, there are several ways in which
>   the application of Content-MD5 to HTTP entity-bodies differs from its
>   application to MIME entity-bodies. One is that **HTTP, unlike MIME, does
>   not use Content-Transfer-Encoding**, and does use Transfer-Encoding and
>   Content-Encoding.

Any ideas for what I should set my headers to?  Thanks.

**EDIT 2**

Many of the code samples found in the comments of this PHP reference manual page seem to suggest that it actually *is* a valid HTTP header:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Why do you want to base64-encode anyway?

Comment: I don't know, I was just given this project.  It's currently in production, so this is how its consumers expect it to behave.

Comment: Well, it's not an HTTP header field, UAs ignore it, and there's really no use for base64 encoding; HTTP allows binary transfers.

Comment: Well; these are very incorrect manual pages then.

Comment: I agree, I don't see why base64 is necessary...if the client needs it encoded in base64, it should do the encoding itself.

Comment: There's no point in base64-encoding; HTTP allows binary payloads, and consequently Content-Transfer-Encoding doesn't exist in HTTP.

Comment: @JulianReschke I agree, that makes sense.

Comment: I've seen that header in a multipart SOAP response from an Apache server. Since SOAP doesn't (usually?) allow binary payloads the file was base64 encoded

Comment: Matthew: there is no Content-Transfer-Encoding header in HTTP. It's meaningless. A server that sends it simply is broken.

Comment: @JulianReschke HTTP allowing one thing unfortunately does not imply it should not also allow a workaround. Web browsers have always had a hard time with binary data.

Comment: @Potaswatter: Web browsers haven't had problems with binary data for decades, otherwise they wouldn't display GIFs and JPGs.

Comment: re edit 2: the PHP code samples simply are wrong; it's unclear to me why the authors refuse to fix them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [RFC 1341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341) (made obsolete by [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)):

> A Content-Transfer-Encoding header field, which  can  be used  to
> specify an auxiliary encoding that was applied to the data in order to
> allow it to pass  through  mail transport  mechanisms  which may have
> data or character set limitations.

and later:

> Many Content-Types which could usefully be  transported  via email
> are  represented, in their "natural" format, as 8-bit character or
> binary data.  Such data cannot  be  transmitted over   some  transport
> protocols.   For  example,  RFC  821 restricts mail messages to 7-bit
> US-ASCII  data  with  1000 character lines.
>
> It is necessary, therefore, to define a  standard  mechanism for
> re-encoding  such  data into a 7-bit short-line format. (...) The
> Content-Transfer-Encoding field is used to indicate  the type  of
> transformation  that  has  been  used  in order to represent the body
> in an acceptable manner for transport.

Since you have a webservice, which has nothing in common with emails, you shouldn't use this header.

You can use `Content-Encoding` header which indicates that transferred data has been compressed (gzip value).

I think that in your case

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

is enough. Additionally, you can set `Content-Length` header, but in my opinion, if you are building webservice (it's not http server / proxy server) `Content-Type` is enough. Please bear in mind that some specific headers (e.g. `Transfer-Encoding`) if not used appropriately, may cause unexpected communication issues, so if you are not 100% sure about usage of some header - if you really need it or not - just don't use it.

Comment: I am setting the Content-Length header.  It might be safer to not add anything...the webservice is working fine the way it is.

Comment: If you know the exact PDF file size and do not use any other HTTP features such as chunking, that's fine to set content-length. It  gives benefits for your users. You can read more here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419281/content-length-header-versus-chunked-encoding

Comment: Yes, I know the length of the file, so it doesn't hurt to set the Content-Length.  The PDF is relatively small (1-1.5MB) so it can all fit into memory and no streaming needs to be done.

Comment: No, HTTP header field names starting with "X-" aren't special at all.

Comment: The header seems to be used a fair amount in SOAP over HTTP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding "The content types defined by MIME standards are also of importance outside of email, such as in communication protocols like HTTP for the World Wide Web. HTTP requires that data be transmitted in the context of email-like messages, although the data most often is not actually email."

Comment: Matthew: please stop adding to the confusion. The Wikipedia page is partly misleading; and despite what you say it doesn't claim C-T-E is used in SOAP.

Comment: Piotrek: "Of course all the time you can send your own headers in wire - all starting with X (e.g. X-Anything) are fully RFC-compliant. " - no, they are not.

Comment: @JulianReschke I've removed this part of answer since it may be confusing. I meant that conventionally non-standard (user defined, experimental) headers are marked with X-. It also seems that this way of marking headers will be deprecated in future (http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-xdash-02)

Comment: Piotrek: The "x-" prefix never was special in HTTP in the first place.

Comment: Note that depreciation of the X- header is an RFC now
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648

Comment: Despite being deprecated, this change was introduced in avoidance of conflicts. More info: https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/api-wg/guidelines/headers.html

Comment: @MatthewLock "HTTP requires that data be transmitted in the context of email-like messages" is not true, whatever Wikipedia says

Answer (score 1):

Notes in rfc2616 section 14.15 are explicit: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

*"Note: while the definition of Content-MD5 is exactly the same for
      HTTP as in RFC 1864 for MIME entity-bodies, there are several ways
      in which the application of Content-MD5 to HTTP entity-bodies
      differs from its application to MIME entity-bodies. **One is that
      HTTP, unlike MIME, does not use Content-Transfer-Encoding**, and
      does use Transfer-Encoding and Content-Encoding. Another is that
      HTTP more frequently uses binary content types than MIME, so it is
      worth noting that, in such cases, the byte order used to compute
      the digest is the transmission byte order defined for the type.
      Lastly, HTTP allows transmission of text types with any of several
      line break conventions and not just the canonical form using CRLF."*

Answer (score 0):

As been answered before and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265902/http-content-encoding-base64), a valid `Content-Transfer-Encoding` HTTP response header does not exist. Also the known headers `Content-Encoding` and `Transfer-Encoding` have no appropriate value to express a Base64 encoded response body.

Starting from here, no client would expect a response declared as `application/pdf` to be encoded as Base64! If you wand to do so, better use a different content type like:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf+base64
```

In this case, a client would know some Base64 encoded data is coming (the basic subtype is the suffix after the plus sign) and has a hint there is PDF in there.

Even this is a little hacky (`+base64` is no [official media type suffix](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-type-structured-suffix/media-type-structured-suffix.xhtml)) but at least would somehow meet some standards. Better use a custom content type than misusing standard HTTP headers!

Of course no browser would be able to directly open such a response anyway. Maybe your project should consider creating another endpoint offering a binary PDF response and marking this one deprecated.