# Convert buffer to base64 string for NgOptimizedImage

Tags: javascript, angular, image

I'm trying to implement `NgOptimizedImage` in my angular app.

```html
<img [ngSrc]="imageUrl" width="196" height="196">
```

`imageUrl` is url to my server. The response is buffer. I used to convert the buffer to string in component.ts file and then using `[src]="convertedBuffer"` show the image. But `NgOptimizedImage` requires src, so it loads from the server when the image can be seen.

Do I have to convert the buffer to string on server, or is there a way to convert it to string on client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on server side.
You have to send `buffer` and set `"Content-Type": "image/TYPE"` header.
If you're using express and nodejs here's how you can do it:

```
res.contentType('image/jpeg'); // set Content-Type header
res.send(buffer); // send buffer. make sure it is buffer (buffer instanceof Buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that. [HTTP doesn't have native support for sending base64-encoded data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265902/http-content-encoding-base64), so the browser won't be able to decipher your image once it is requested.

Base64 is only supported in [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). It seems that you have to convert your server to send non-base64-encoded images or go back to your old way of displaying images.