# Hide the real file path to prevent hotlinking

Tags: php

I am using the following code to hide the real file path to prevent hotlinking. Whenever I try to download the file through newly created address, everything including the file size and the file name are ok, but, when I try to open the file, whether a PDF file or a ZIP file, it says that the file is damaged.

When I download the file directly from the server, it works and it doesn't have any problems.

```
$file = 'file.pdf';

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/files/';

$file_Path = $path . $file;

list($file_Basename, $file_Ext) = explode('.', $file);

switch($file_Ext)
{
    case "pdf": $ctype = "application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype = "application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype = "application/zip"; break;
    case "rar": $ctype = "application/rar"; break;
    case "doc": $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-word"; break;
    case "xls": $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype = "image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype = "image/png"; break;
    default: $ctype = "application/force-download";
}

header('Content-Type:'. $ctype);

header('Content-Length:' . filesize($file_Path));

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

readfile($file_Path);

exit();
```

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Check the contents of the file in a text editor to see whether it's really what you expect it to be.

Comment: @PeeHaa yes it is. when I download the file normally from the server, it works.

Comment: @Martin doesn't help. I still get the same error.

Comment: ok, then I'd hazard that your filesize is not quite correct somehow, so try and comment out the Content-Length header and see if the download works using the dynamic size rather than a stated fixed size.

Comment: @RyanVincent I checked it. However, I don't understand what is going on inside two files. But, this is the result : Added(155)Deleted(796)Changed(405)

Comment: @Martin in this way the file download after some time delay and it works. What should I do?!

Comment: [ok try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981159/should-content-transfer-encoding-headers-be-use-when-downloading-files-via-http). If this works you can maybe reinstate the filesize header

Comment: @Martin When I remove the transfer encoding, I still get the file damaged error. But, commenting out the file size doesn't hurt the file. Do you think that I have to remove the contect-length ?!

Comment: I can't say for sure why, but I guess from your trial and errors that it's easiest to work with just the *Content-Type* and *Content-Disposition* headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code and added `ob_clean()` and `flush()` to make it work:

```
header('Content-Type:'. $ctype);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file->file_Name.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_Path));

//This part must be added to your code
if (ob_get_length() > 0 ) {
    ob_clean();
    flush();
}

readfile($file_Path);

exit();
```