# Headers for REST API with optional Base64 encoding

Tags: rest, http, header

We have a media file repository, with which other services communicate over a REST API. For various reasons we want the users of the repository to be able to upload and download files over HTTP both directly (plaintext for text files and byte array for binary files) and using Base64 encoding. We want the fact that the file is uploaded (PUT, POST) and requested for download (GET) in the Base64 encoding be reflected in the header of the HTTP request.

**How do we reflect the fact that the content of the request or requested response is Base64 encoded in the HTTP header?**

So far I'm tending towards appending `;base64` after the mime type in the `Content-Type` header, for example `Content-Type: image/png;base64`. Other options (`X-` header, `Content-Encoding`) are discussed [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285372/is-content-transfer-encoding-an-http-header#7289434) but do not offer satisfactory resolution to our question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

It is in **RFC** https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-14.

It supports `base64` value among others, like `"7bit" / "8bit" / "binary" /                   "quoted-printable" / "base64" / ietf-token / x-token`

This header is specially designed for your case, to use as a complement for MIME type.

Comment: There is no Content-Transfer-Encoding in HTTP.

Comment: "There is no Content-Transfer-Encoding in HTTP." Correct. It is for email only.