# What is the correct content-type for a base64 image?

Tags: ajax, http, web, mime-types

I have a server-side script which generates an image in response to an AJAX call.

In order to show the image on the page, I am encoding it with Base64.

However, I am not sure what to put in the "content-type" header.

"image/png" seems wrong because the content is actually text which encodes a png, and not actually a png.

"text/plain" seems wrong because it implies plain text and also nginx will try to compress it which is a waste of time as the compression savings will be minimal.

What is the actual correct way to go?

(Also, could I send it as a png and let the client convert it to base64?)

Comment: Related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285372/is-content-transfer-encoding-an-http-header

Answer (score 0):

No, I think the issue is not in the content-type, but your server can not get FONT Configuration. Therefor, I can not return texts in Image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).