# Viewing PDF file on local sever showed correctly, but shown symbols on live server

Tags: php

PDF file shown symbols  on live server while fetched from database, but displayed correctly on local sever. I don’t know exactly what I am doing wrong.

Below is my code

```
<?php
    if(ISSET($_REQUEST['file'])){
        $file = $_REQUEST['file'];

        // Add header to load pdf file
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' .$file. '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
// @readfile($file);
    @readfile("files/".$file);
    }
?>
```

[Here is a sample displayed symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhqOp.png)

Comment: suggestion: force download instead. Try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485886/force-file-download-with-php-using-header)

Comment: Do you have a navigator pdf reader? CAN you get it by removing headers one by one?

Comment: Don't use [`Content-Transfer-Encoding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285372/is-content-transfer-encoding-an-http-header).

Comment: And check the value of the `Content-type` header returned by the live server.

Comment: @Ken Lee, I needed to view the PDF and not to download it. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much at @K J, the file itself is save on a folder called "files", while only the path is save in the database. My concern is that, this works fine on local server without any issues.