# Laravel (9x): Model is saving/creating the record twice

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, response

I'm developing a very small and simple application, it has a route that returns a `png` response and also creates a new record in the database when the png URL is being called.
I'm not sure why I see this strange behavior (check the tracing).

**Tracing:** When commenting out the code `->header('Content-Type', 'image/png')` it inserts only one row as expected, but the png is returned as binary data which is also expected when removing it.

**The problem:** With one url call, it inserts two rows in the table at once.

**Expected behavior:** With one url call, it should insert only one row in the table.

*The Controller:*

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\EmailTrackerHistory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\EmailTracker;

class EmailTrackerController extends Controller
{
    public function getPixel(Request $request)
    {
        $trackerId = $request->get('tracker');
        $filename = 'ma-logo.png';

        $model = EmailTracker::find($trackerId);

        if ($model->empty_pixel == true) {
            $filename = 'pixel.png';
        }

        $img = public_path($filename);

        $history = new EmailTrackerHistory();
        $history->email_tracker_id = $trackerId;
        $history->open_time = now(); // Use Laravel's now() to get the current date and time
        $history->opener_ip = $request->ip();
        $history->opener_user_agent = $request->userAgent();

        if ($history->save()) {
            $content = file_get_contents($img);

            return response($content)
                ->header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
                ->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="' . $filename . '"')
                ->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
                ->header('Expires', '0')
                ->header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
                ->header('Pragma', 'public')
                ->header('Content-Length', strlen($content));
        }

        abort(500); // If save fails, return a server error response
    }
}
```

*The Model (default):*

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EmailTrackerHistory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

*The Router:*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmailTrackerController;

Route::get('/logo.png', [EmailTrackerController::class, 'getPixel'])->name('getPixel');
```

Comment: Not related to your issue, but why are you using the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header?

Comment: *"With one url call, it inserts two rows in the table"* How do you know there is only one call?

Comment: @Olivier The Content-Transfer-Encoding header is used to specify the encoding method used to represent binary data in a textual format when transmitted over a network, typically in the context of email messages or HTTP responses.

This can be removed and it will also work fine.

Comment: @Olivier That's why I included the trace part ..

Comment: Check this out: [Is Content-Transfer-Encoding an HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285372/is-content-transfer-encoding-an-http-header)

Comment: What do you mean by "trace part"?

Comment: The trace part:
Tracing: When commenting out the code `->header('Content-Type', 'image/png')` it inserts only one row as expected, but the png is returned as binary data which is also expected when removing it.

Comment: Which tends to prove that there is a single insert per URL call. When the client receives the `image/png` content-type, it then probably sends a second request to the URL (for some reason).

Comment: When calling the asset png directly (without going through the controller) in the browser, it doesn't insert any records

Comment: Of course. Why would it?

Comment: I know, it doesn't make sense, but who knows.

Comment: You are right .. in Google Chrome Inspector.. when calling the URL, for some reason it calls it twice in the network tab .. but why?