File size is not visible in php download readfile
I used below code to force browser start download:
//send file
$fileName = basename($fullPath);
$length = filesize($fullPath);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-length: ' .  $length);
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");

readfile($fullPath);

exit;

Everything's ok except total file size is not showing in browser (Firefox & Chrome). I searched the community and also test below code in htaccess with no success :
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ...
My web server is Apache and PHP is in version 8.3
Is there any other option to check?

Probably not related to your problem, but I'm pretty sure you can remove Content-Transfer-Encoding completely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7289434/231316

If your filename has special characters, you might also want to consider quoting it, too, just in case something is getting mangled there.

did you check if $length contains the correct file size?

@ChrisHaas Thanks for your comment. I don't know what is doing exactly :)

@NasserHajlawi yes it has some integer value

Recently I had the same problem! Suggest that add this header too rather than htaccess solution
//to show file-size in browser
header("Content-Encoding: none");

